# Replace hardcoded localhost to dynamic one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to replace the hardcoded localhost with a dynamic one.
This is my code :

```
  export default {
   data: function() 
    {
    return {
        localhost: "http://10.10.10.132/",
           };
    },
    }
```

Is it's possible to change the localhost to something like this:

```
   export default {
   data: function() 
    {
    return {
        localhost: window.location.host,
           };
    },
    }
```

When I use the

```
  localhost: window.location.host
```

My API request is duplicated -  http://10.10.10.132/10.10.10.132
Thanks.

Comment: `localhost` is a pre-defined name for `127.0.0.1`. Use a different name, maybe just `host` to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `origin` instead of `host` :

```
   export default {
      data: function() 
       {
         return {
              localhost: window.location.origin,
           };
       },
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.host` doesn't include the protocol:

```js
return {
   localhost: window.location.origin
}
```

But guessing from your problem where the API request gets "duplicated" as you said. You don't need the localhost anyways. If you don't specify the baseUrl (= domain/IP, port and protocol) it will automatically direct the request to localhost.

So instead of making a request to `localhost/api/something` you can just do `/api/something`

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.host` returns url without protocol, so change it to:

```js
return {
  localhost: 'http://'+window.location.host,
}
```